# When to use Data.Coerce?

Tags: haskell

In the `inline-c` package, there's an [example](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/inline-c-0.9.1.4/src/examples/gsl-ode.hs) calling the C library GNU Scientific Library `gsl` from Haskell.

```
solveOde fun x0 f0 xend =
  coerce $ solveOdeC (coerce fun) (coerce x0) (coerce f0) (coerce xend)
```

I'm trying to wrap more of `gsl` in Haskell and I try to understand every line of the example code. So why it uses `Data.Coerce` here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of `solveOdeC` is almost the same as the type for `solveOde`. The former type involves `CDouble` at several points, including inside `Vector`s and `Either`. The latter instead uses `Double`.

The code relies on `CDouble` and `Double` having the same representation. Because of that, using `coerce` one can define a function by simply calling the other one with no runtime overhead. Without that, one would need to create a new `Vector` which would be bitwise identical to the first one only to satisfy the type checker, spending O(N) for this overhead.

To be honest, I find the definition in the library unnecessarily verbose. One could have written, instead,

```
solveOde = coerce solveOdeC
```

Comment: to be pedantic, wouldn't it be better to say "no runtime overhead", instead of "essentially zero overhead"?